# Cannot logout Facebook in android app when device has installed Facebook app?

Tags: android, facebook, session-cookies, logout

I develop an android app login by account Facebook using Facebook SDK 3.0. I use Facebook app to login, my device remembers account info.
When I develop logout in my app used UserSettingsFragment build-in Facebook SDK, it cannot logout because my device always remembers account info from Facebook app?

I search google, with Facebook 2.0, you can use

```
Facebook face = new Facebook("app_id");
face.logout(this);
```

But it deprecated in Facebook 3.0, so I use

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
Utility.clearFacebookCookies(this);
```

But it doesn't work! Any idea?